# Is there a way to identify certain key words to answer a yes/no question in python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a chatbot that takes yes/no answers, and I wish to include the more common ways to say yes. At first, I tried 2 lists containing answers:

```
Positives = ["Yes", "Yeah", "Sure", "Absolutely", "yes", "yeah", "sure", "absolutely"]
Negatives = ["no", "nah", "maybe", "No", "Nah", "Maybe"]
```

I thought I could use every element of `Positives` in an if statement, where it would be like:

```
answer1 = input("prompt")
if Positives[] in answer1:
    print("positive answer found")
elif Negatives[] in answer1:
    print("Negative answer found")
else:
    print("???")
```

I ended up with:

```
if Positives[0] or Positives[1] or Positives[2] or Positives[3] \
        or Positives[4] or Positives[5] or Positives[6] or Positives[7] in answer1:
    print("Positives detected")

if Negatives[0] or Negatives[1] or Negatives[2] or Negatives[3] or Negatives[4] \
    or Negatives[5] in answer1:
    print("Negatives detected")
```

I found that in using `upper`, I'd only get fully capitalized strings, which would have made my `if` statements more unnecessarily verbose. Moreover, when I've executed such code, I've found myself with `Positives detected` regardless. If there is a way to utilize each individual string of a list in an `if` statement, I'd love to know if such a package or library is available. Moreover, I'd like an explanation as to what I've done wrong in the current code.

Comment: `if answer1 in Positives:` ... you just have the order written incorrectly.

Comment: Also, covert the user input to lowercase so you don't have to worry about variations. `if answer1.lower() in Positives`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
positives = ["yes", "yeah", "sure", "absolutely"]
negatives = ["no", "nah", "maybe"]

# user may input something other than what we have. in that case repeat the prompt.
while True:
    answer1 = input("prompt")
    # convert the answer to lowercase, then check if it is in list of postives.
    if answer1.lower() in positives:  
        print("positive answer found")
        # if found break the loop
        break
    # convert the answer to lowercase, then check if it is in list of negatives.
    if answer1.lower() in negatives:
        print("Negative answer found")
        # if found break the loop
        break
    # if there was no break when code reach this line. 
    # That means user entered something else, so repeat the prompt.
    print("That is not a valid response")
    continue
```